# How to display custom error message in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, message

I am trying to limit file upload size on my site and using the following code (which works fine):

```
function limit_upload_size( $file ) {

// Set the desired file size limit
$file_size_limit = 1024; // 1MB in KB

// exclude admins
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

    $current_size = $file['size'];
    $current_size = $current_size / 1024; //get size in KB

    if ( $current_size > $file_size_limit ) {
        $file['error'] = sprintf( __( 'ERROR: File size limit is %d KB.' ), $file_size_limit );
    }

}

return $file;

}
add_filter ( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'limit_upload_size', 10, 1 );
```

The only problem I've encountered is that the error message doesn't display.
When I change

```
$file['error'] = sprintf( __( 'ERROR: File size limit is %d KB.' ), $file_size_limit );
```

to

```
 $file['error'] = sprintf( __e( 'ERROR: File size limit is %d KB.' ), $file_size_limit );
```

I see the following error message instead:
Error #-200: HTTP Error instead of the custom error message.

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `__()` returns the translated text, while `_e()` displays/echos it. And as you are inside `sprintf()` function, you need the returned translated text, not display it to the screen.

[_e() codex reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e),
[__() codex reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/__)

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So what would be the solution?    Using  $file['error'] = sprintf( __( 'ERROR: File size limit is %d KB.' ), $file_size_limit );  doesn't return an error message....

Comment: Just keep using the `__()` function. What's wrong with it?

Comment: It would be fine, only the error message isn't returned - I cannot see it... ?

Comment: It's showing the error for me. By any chance, are you logged in as an admin user?

Comment: do I need to specify some kind of specific <div> on my page to be able to return the error message? (sorry I'm quite a newbie to php)

Comment: It's working as it should be for me. https://imgur.com/isOjUds. I am testing this from the media uploader page in the backend. Where are you testing it from?

Comment: I have a frontend uploader for users, maybe that is the reason. Is there a way to just echo the error message instead (if it will solve the issue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197704/discussion-between-gul-jamal-zim-and-elektra).